# Help with AutoFS

Tags: nfs, autofs

AutoFS has been kicking my butt the last few times I have tried it.

I have it installed and running, edited the `auto.master` and an `auto.network` file under `/etc`, but can't get it to mount my NFS directory. I can mount it via command line using

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.55:/mnt/md0/Videos /mnt/videos
```

but can't seem to get it to mount using AutoFS. Would anyone be able to provide me with an `auto.master` and `auto.network` file that could mount this directory?

Comment: Show us your `auto.master` and `auto.network` files by Editing  ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/940698/edit ) your post, adding the text and formatting it with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new empty directory under `/mnt` for the autofs mounts to be added.

```
mkdir /mnt/network
```

Edit `/etc/auto.master`

```
/mnt/network        /etc/auto.network
```

Edit `/etc/auto.network`

```
videos    -rw     192.168.0.55:/mnt/md0/Videos
```

Restart autofs

```
systemctl restart autofs
```

If you access `/mnt/network/videos` (i.e. via `cd` or `ls`) the directory should auto-mount and be accessible.